# how to solve milp with min-max function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to solve a Mixed Integer Linear Programming(MILP). but optimize a min-max objective
function is my problem. would you please help me? Do you know any way or solver to solve it? 
thanks in advance
example:
    min max -3x1+2x2+x3 subject to:
    x3 binary
    x1,x2 >=0
    x1+x2+x3<=7
    4x1+2x2+x3=12

Comment: Can you add more detail at your question? code, examples, etc .. it is not clear enough

Comment: I want to optimize it: